# Need input for search line excel

Tags: python, pandas, excel

```
import pandas as pd

def calculadora():
   nivel = input()
   df = pd.read_excel("Abc.csv" , nrows = "nivel" ,)
   display(df)
calculadora()
```

ValueError: 'nrows' must be an integer >=0

i want search line on excel.

Comment: Don't edit your question to be completely different from what you originally asked. Accept an answer if you've received one that answers your question, and then ask a new question

Comment: You need an extra level of four-space indentation for your code to show up properly-formatted. But it doesn't make much sense. What is `h`? Did you mean the literal character `'h'`? 

Regardless, a `datetime` value always has a year, month and day (and minute and second) in it. If you want to print out just the hour part, use `strftime`, which works like `strptime` in reverse.

Comment: Well, never mind, I guess, since you have switched to a completely different question!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the variable `nivel` to be used, then you need to remove the quotes around it.

`df = pd.read_excel("Abc.csv" , nrows = nivel)`